# Merging tags [howto] and [how-to]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

Both *[howto](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/howto)* and *[how-to](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-to)* tags refer to the same thing and thus should be merged.

Answer (score 5):

That tag should be removed completely. It's pointless and doesn't serve to categorise the content in any meaningful way.

It's a given that if you're asking a question on how to do something that you want to know how to do something.

Adding that tag doesn't help since it's more a stop word bloating out the tag list.

**how to** be  a zero
The tags are now at zero count. When the [daily "kill tags that aren't being used on any question" script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags) is run and they're toasted, the only way for it to come back is if a user with a [reputation of at least 300](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags) knowingly puts it into a question.

Comment: is 100% correct -- please see the SO blog post [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for explanation/rationale

Comment: @Eight: The tag might also re-appear if it's on a migrated question.

Comment: Migrated questions with tags that don't appear at the destination site will be stripped from the question. @ale

Comment: You sure? We killed the "android" tag multiple times at android.se and migrated questions resurrected it until we finally got the blacklist straightened out. I'll be glad to be proven wrong, though.

Comment: Absolutely not sure on automatic stripping of dead tags to destination site. @ale